# Prevent Thread Subclass from waiting

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a coding game for the Java class I TA. The game is to manage a fleet of trucks (`Truck extends Thread`) on an undirected graph to deliver parcels to their various destinations using as little time/fuel as possible. The student extends an abstract manager class that fills in the gaps in the Truck's behavior (what to do upon reaching a destination, etc). The truck class's run method is a event loop that waits for user instruction and then follows it when it receives travel destinations. Here's the event loop:

```
@Override
/** The Truck's main running routine. While the travel directions are empty,
 * Waits for more instructions in WAIT_TIME intervals. While the travel directions
 * are not empty, pops off the next travel direction 
 */
public void run(){
    while(game.isRunning()){

        setGoingTo(null);

        while(travel.isEmpty() && game.isRunning()){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setStatus(Status.WAITING);
            game.getScore().changeScore(Score.WAIT_COST);
        }
        while(!travel.isEmpty() && game.isRunning()){
            Edge r = getTravel();
            try {
                travel(r);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first inner while loop loops while there are no travel instructions to follow. As you can see, every WAIT_TIME milliseconds (a frame), the score is decreased by the wait cost - the cost of the truck idling.
I realized, however, that a way for a potential solution to get around this cost is to tell the truck (thread) to wait while it doesn't have instructions, then notify it once the user has computed instructions for it. I'd like to prevent this programmatically, rather than just put in the instructions not to do it.

Is this even possible? Perhaps a method in the thread class to override? Can a class that extends Thread be prevented from waiting (on anything?) I'd settle for any kind of exception being thrown if a truck thread tries to execute .wait().

Thanks for reading and for any suggestions for how to tackle this gap in the rules! The game will be up on a public repo soon if you want to try your hand at it.

Comment: Truck should probably not extend Thread.  Extending a class implies a true "is a" relationship.

Comment: I agree, but it's close enough and the game is designed to teach threads + graph algorithm stuff. So while it may make more sense another way, I'd lose the teaching goals along the way.

Comment: If you are teaching threads, that's all the more reason not to extend thread, since that would be a bad example of how they are used...

Comment: Thinking about it more I think you're right. Making truck implement runnable both makes more sense and doesn't change its current behavior.

Comment: If `sleep` is forbidden, why can't they use a simple long running loop? The only way check it properly - do code review.

Comment: If the game is designed to teach threads the most likely outcome will be that you will learn that using threads for this kind of purpose is the wrong approach. Threads are for *concurrency* that means entities which have no timely relationship. In contrast, your tracks are supposed to run in a common (simulated) time which is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for the exact question you asked (how to prevent wait), but a suggestion that is kind of too long for a comment:

How about measuring the time between the start of the first while loop and the end.

```
long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
setStatus(Status.WAITING);
while(travel.isEmpty() && game.isRunning()){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long waittime = endtime - starttime;
game.getScore().changeScore(Score.WAIT_COST * (1 + waittime / WAIT_TIME));
```

Even if the thread is sent to sleep, the score will change according to the ellapsed time. You will just not have a live game score update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't prevent `.sleep()` or `.wait()` because you can't override or tamper with them. So the only way is monitoring for them.

I don't know of a method inside the thread but from outside the thread (for example from a monitoring thread) you can get the thread staus with

```
Thread.getState()
```

if someone called `sleep` on the thread or the thread is waiting becuase of a `wait` call the result should be `Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING`. Then all you have to ensure is that the monitoriong thread knows it were the students that called sleep and not you (a private flag for example).

The monitoring thread can then of course take any counter measures you want like throwing an Exception or simply silently decucting points.

Relevant docs :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()

Comment: This prevents them from using their own Thread.sleep() (which is half the battle). Is there also a way to check for them making the thread wait? A different state return?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether having a Thread per Truck is the right approach.  Are you trying to teach them about threads? or are you trying to teach them about graph algorithms and heuristics?  (If the Single Responsibility Principle applies to homework assignments, then the answer should be one or the other, but not both.)

If the emphasis was on algorithms and heuristics, then I would write a single-threaded program where the main loop executes a series of "moves".  In each move, it would ask each of the truck objects what the truck wants to do next, and then it would either move the truck accordingly, or it would flag the assignment as invalid if the truck asked to do something that did not make sense.

In my version, the "time" in the simulation would be completely decoupled from real-time, so if some student put a Thread.sleep() in her/his strategy routine, it would not have any effect on the outcome of the program; it only would make the program take that much longer to run.  (Of course, I would run them all under control of a batch script that would abort any assignment that took longer than... say, three minutes.)